# JS pagination with twbspagination plugin and AJAX update after third onPageClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

First of all i want to say that I'm a newbie in jQuery so my question could be silly or something like that.
I want to use this jQuery plugin for AJAX pagination: http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/ and I have implemented this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var params = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(1);
if (params[2] == null) {
    params[2] = 10;
}
countPages('http://losuj-mirka.byethost7.com/countPages/', params[2])
    .done(function (data) {
        $('ul.pagination').empty();
        $('ul.pagination').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: data.pagesAmount,
            visiblePages: 5,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                console.log(page);
                if (params[1] == 0 || params[1] == null) {
                    params[1] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    params[1] = page;
                }
                useAjax('http://losuj-mirka.byethost7.com/archives/ajaxArchives/', params)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        $('#archives-table tbody').html(data.result);
                    })
            }
        });
    });
```

});

```
function countPages(url, limit) {
return $.ajax({
    url: url + limit,
    data: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
})
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('AJAX error.')
    });
```

}

```
function useAjax(url, params) {
return $.ajax({
    url: url + params[1] + '/' + params[2],
    data: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
})
    .fail(function () {
        console.log('AJAX error.')
    });
```

}

But that code replace my table after third onPageClick event what You can check here: http://losuj-mirka.byethost7.com/archives/ 
Is it because of my faulty implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this line

```
var params = window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(1);
```

you get `["archives", ""]` as the value of `param`. So `param[1]` has value of `""`.

That's why when this condition first runs, it returns `false`.

```
if (params[1] == 0 || params[1] == null) {
    params[1] = 1;
}
```

You can try updating that condition as:

```
if (params[1] == 0 || params[1] == null || params[1] == "") {
    params[1] = 1;
}
```

That might solve your problem. I can't be entirely certain because I can't try it in a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help, I have solved it this way. In onPageClick event I set params without any 'if conditional' and it's working. Thanks for help because I had no idea where was a mistake.